# using dynamic column names in mysql join query

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

Is there a way to dynamically pull column names from select query.

```
table->country
 (countryID | countryName)

table->countryVars
(countryID | dataKey | dataVal)
```

basic idea is to get something that this would do so you don't have to
case every column name but just add key/val pair to countryVars table

```
select country.*, countryVars.dataVal as countryVars.dataKey form country
join countryVars on countryVars.countryID = country.countryID
```

end result should be like this

```
countryID | countryName | capital  | people | region

1         | Finland     | Helsinki | 5milj  | scandinavia
```

Comment: You're looking for a "pivot" or "cross tab" query.

Comment: thanks @Uueerdo
Got my confirmation that its best to do it out side of database!

Comment: For Pivoting in MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831